# Assertion Failure in Calculator Program

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, macos, cocoa

So I'm working on a simple calculator program to get used to cocoa and objective C. I've redone the whole thing multiple times and every time I finish coding, the first time i build it, it works fine, but every time after that the window wont launch and it gives me these errors:

```
2013-01-11 10:32:14.760 Visual Caluclator Fix[39892:403] *** Assertion failure in -[NSTextFieldCell _objectValue:forString:errorDescription:], /SourceCache/AppKit/AppKit-1138.47/AppKit.subproj/NSCell.m:1564
2013-01-11 10:32:14.762 Visual Caluclator Fix[39892:403] Ignoring exception raised in __-[NSPersistentUIManager restoreAllPersistentStateWithTalagentWindows:registeringAsReadyWhenDone:completionHandler:]_block_invoke_3: Invalid parameter not satisfying: aString != nil
```

I've concluded that the problem lies in my textEdited method, because when I comment the code inside of it out, the program has no issues running; however, I have no idea why this is, or why it would run the first time and not any subsequent times. When I put in an exception breakpoint, it points me to the one line in the updateUI method and the call to [self updateUI] in the textEdited method. The following code is the textEdited method and the other methods it references.(I'm fairly sure there's nothing wrong with the solve method because I used it in a command prompt calculator and it worked great. Also, I know this is a pretty convoluted way to program a calculator, with the strings and everything, but I was just trying to integrate the code I already had for the command prompt program into a cocoa program.)

In the AppDelegate class:

```
- (void)updateUI{
    [self.calculationView setStringValue: self.calculation.calcString];//Exception breakpoint points here
}

- (IBAction)textEdited:(id)sender {
    self.calculation.calcString = self.calculationView.stringValue;
    [self.calculation solve];
    [self updateUI];//Exception breakpoint points here
}
```

In the Calculation class:

```
- (NSString*)solve{
    for (int i = 0; i < [self.calcString length]; i++) {
        NSRange nextChar = NSMakeRange(i, 1);
        if ([[self.calcString substringWithRange: nextChar] isEqualToString: @"*"]||
            [[self.calcString substringWithRange: nextChar] isEqualToString: @"/"])
            [self calcTerm: i];
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < [self.calcString length]; i++) {
        NSRange nextChar = NSMakeRange(i, 1);
        if ([[self.calcString substringWithRange: nextChar] isEqualToString: @"+"]||
            [[self.calcString substringWithRange: nextChar] isEqualToString: @"-"])
            [self calcTerm: i];
    }
    return self.calcString;
}
```

Comment: What kind of object is `self.calculationView`?

Answer (score 1):

This might help with your problem:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/10505/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-2

The site explains how assertion errors work and demonstrate how you would fix an error like that.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like something in `calcTerm:` is setting `calcString` to `nil`. Thus, when you retrieve it later to set the field's string value to it, you end up setting the field's string value to `nil`, which it doesn't like.

You can check this by logging the value of `calcString` just before the end of `solve`. Then, start stringing up log statements and/or breakpoints in `calcTerm:` to find out how you're swapping out your string for `nil`.